# jQuery Lite Content Slider - Adding class to current slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a "current" class to the slide div that is not hidden? I've been poking at this for a while and was wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

http://jsfiddle.net/e7VZS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e7VZS/3/)**

I have modified `goToSlide` method. Added the callback method to `animate` method in which I am adding the `current` class on the current slide.

```
$('.slider-contents-wrap' + ' ' + theClass)
                .animate({
                    left: animateLeft
                }, function(){
                    $element
                        .children(options.content).removeClass('current')
                        .filter(':eq('+(theSlide-1)+')')
                        .addClass('current');

                });
```

Comment: Ah! Very nice, but I guess this isn't setting the first slide to "current" on load. Any idea why?